# How to group by two rows in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a two table data and location with 
table data hold location,id,name...
table location hold location and id...

```
table location
id    location
1     offshore
2     onsite

id   location    name
1      offshore   A
2      offshore   B
3      offshore   C
```

how to get output like

```
id location Name
1    offshore   A
1    onsite     Null
```

Comment: And why would the query return `'A'` as opposed to some other value?

Comment: select * from data d left join location l on l.location=d.location where id=1

Answer (score 0):

Left join `location` table on `data` to get all locations regardless if there is match in `data` table, group by location id and location, and I assume you want to get the 1st name (min()):

```
select l.id, l.location, min(d.name) as name
from location l
left join data d on l.location=d.location
group by l.id, l.location
```

Alternatively, if you want to get for a data item if it has offshore and onshore record:

```
select d.id, l.location, d2.name
from location l
join data d
left join data d2 on l.location=d2.location
where d.id=1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from data d left join location l on l.location=d.location group by location
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.